# JBoss 4.0.5 + Equinox + JPA + EclipseLink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, equinox, jboss-4.0.x

I'm trying to connect the JPA (EclipsLink implementation) used on my application to JBoss DS, but don't know how to do it.

The application that I'm working is a OSGi Based application runing on a Equinox container that runs as a servlet on a JBoss WAR file.

How can I configure my application so that it connects the JBoss DS?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds pretty complicated.  What have you tried, and what error are you getting?

Normally you just set the datasource in the JPA persistence.xml, does that work?

Comment: Currently I'm getting 11:41:20,858 INFO  [STDOUT] [EL Warning]: 2012-09-24 11:41:20.858--The temporary classLoader for PersistenceLoadProcessor [tn] is not available.  Switching classLoader to [org.ecli
pse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.osgi.CompositeClassLoader@54174e5].  Weaving has been disabled for this session. EclipseLink may be unable to get a spec mandated temporary
class loader from the server, you may be able to use static weaving as an optional workaround.

Comment: Seems like a warning, not an error? Does your app still work?  If you want weaving in JBoss you must use static weaving.